# Simulating the C++ Command-Line Parameters with Variables

Tags: c++, dll, command-line

I'm trying to convert a C++ source code to dll . For this I change `wmain` to `MyMethod` and change the Configuration Type of this source into a Dynamic Library (.dll) .

Now MyMethod is like :

```
int MyMethod(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{    }
```

After this I pass args to this file like :

```
   MyFile.exe -a arg1 -b "arg2"
```

Now I want to do the same way into dll manually so as someone describes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425743/converting-an-exe-to-dll-calling-the-main-function-manually) I change my code to :

```
  int MyMethod(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    int argc1 = 2;
    wchar_t *argv1[2] = { L"-a arg1",L"-b arg2" };
    argc = argc1;
    argv = argv1;
}
```

But the above code doesn't have the same effects as Command-Line.

What makes this code wrong ?!(I mean do the command-line assign variables something different ?)

**Update 1 :**
My wmain method is :

```
    int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
    {
        int argc1 = 3;
        wchar_t *argv1[3] = { L"" , L"-a arg1",L"-b arg2" };

        argc = argc1;
        argv = argv1;

        if (!ArgTranslate(argc, argv))
        {
            MessageBoxA(0, "Error", "Not valid args", 0);
            return -1;
        }
    MessageBoxA(0, "Valid", "It is valid", 0);
    return 0;
}

bool ArgTranslate(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{

    wchar_t* Parm1= NULL;   
    wchar_t* Parm2= NULL;   

    for (int i = 1; (i < argc) && ((i + 1) < argc); i += 2)
    {
        if (wcscmp(argv[i], L"-a") == 0)
            Parm1 = argv[i + 1];
        else if (wcscmp(argv[i], L"-b") == 0)
            Parm2 = argv[i + 1]; 
    }
    if (Parm1 == NULL || Parm2 == NULL)
        return false;
    else
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to copy these `char*` pointers explicitly. `std::copy()` is suitable to do so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wouldn't it be simply UB if the original `argv` is not long enough to store the new number of `wchar_t*`s?

Comment: @Rostislav It's anyway unclear what the OPs asking for here. Trying to change the originally passed `argc` `argv` parameters without a reference won't work.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, unless they are only used in `MyMethod` and its callees. But it seems that OP is a bit lost, so it's all a moot point :)

Comment: You might be able to use [GetCommandLine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510167/what-is-the-command-line-at-getcommandline-and-at-winmain-api) to retrieve the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to the main function is the name of the executable itself. 
From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function):

> argv[0] is the pointer to the initial character of a null-terminated multibyte strings that represents the name used to invoke the program itself (or an empty string "" if this is not supported by the execution environment)

If it's not used, you can just provide an empty string - so in your case you will have `argc1 = 3` and `argv1[3] = {L"", L"-a arg1",L"-b arg2" };`

---

**Edit**
I provided the simple fix in the comments. Here's a version which is slightly closer to C++11 and also doesn't use the unnecessary temporaries and assignment to `main`'s arguments

```
#include <array>

bool ArgTranslate(int argc, wchar_t const* argv[])
{
    wchar_t const* Parm1 = nullptr;   
    wchar_t const* Parm2 = nullptr;   

    for (int i = 1; (i + 1) < argc; i += 2)
    {
        if (wcscmp(argv[i], L"-a") == 0)
            Parm1 = argv[i + 1];
        else if (wcscmp(argv[i], L"-b") == 0)
            Parm2 = argv[i + 1]; 
    }
    if (!Parm1 || !Parm2)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    std::array<wchar_t const*, 5> args{L"" , L"-a", L"arg1", L"-b",  L"arg2"};

    if (!ArgTranslate(static_cast<int>(args.size()), args.data()))
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "Error", "Not valid args", 0);
        return -1;
    }
    MessageBoxA(0, "Valid", "It is valid", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might be right but after changing my method nothing happened ! (same as what it was before)

Comment: @Sinaei Well, then more information is needed. Who calls `MyMethod`? Which function uses `argc` and `argv`? `MyMethod` itself or its caller?

Comment: MyMethod and another methods use Argv and Argc but I assign it ! I don't thing this is problem .And MyMethod is calling from another cpp file .

Comment: @Sinaei well, that really depends... What you do is assign the local copies of these variables and you don't modify the values for the caller of `MyMethod`. So if `MyMethod` calls some function with its own `argc` and `argv`, then it will be fine. The _caller_ of `MyMethod` will not see any changes. The answer thus depends on who calls whom.

Comment: So its simple I completely remove any arguments and MyMethod comes like MyMethod() but its still the same effects !!! Do you know how can I completely print argv from main file to see what happens in exe file ?!

Comment: Could you show your `main`? And the call to your `MyMethod`? Otherwise it's impossible to help

Comment: @Sinaei Well, basically you actually expect 5 arguments, when giving it only 3 - "-a" and "-b" should be separate arguments. The easy fix is `int argc1 = 5;` and `wchar_t *argv1[5] = { L"" , L"-a", L"arg1", L"-b",  L"arg2" };`. I will provide a slightly better way to do the same thing in my answer.